# Formatting python timedelta result

Tags: python, datetime, jinja2, timedelta

I am trying to calculate elapsed time in Python between a specific time and current time.

Following is a code:

```
start_time = q.entrydate              // type datetime.datetime
end_time = datetime.now()             // type datetime.datetime
elapsed = end_time - start_time       // type datetime.timedelta

# For Jinja2 template
self.view['elapsed'] = test
```

and in jinja2 template (html) `{{ elapsed }}`

Calculation works fine but I want to format the result like ex.

This result:

```
1 day, 20:04:27.258579
```

to be ike this:

```
1 day, 20 hours, 4 minutes (without seconds)
```

Comment: You'll have to manually format it in your view; see the dupe.